# Android 12/13 Signing images fails with error in sign_target_files_apks due to missing file vendor.img when vendor binaries are added

Tags: android, android-source, ota, android-signing, android-12l

Attempting to build an image from AOSP 12 for OTA package, the `sign_target_files_apks` utility fails due to missing `vendor.img` file. The error occurs only after vendor binaries are added. Same thing with AOSP 13, error occurs only after vendor binaries are added.

Target is **Google Pixel 3a "Sargo"**, OS is **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**, AOSP version tag is `android-12.1.0_r27`.

I added the correct device binaries downloaded from [Google's website](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers), compiled and flashed to a Pixel 3a device (codename Sargo) successfully.

Then attempted building an OTA package following google's documentation on [Signing Builds for Release](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/sign_builds) to generate the keys, [Building OTA Packages](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/tools) to build the actual OTA package, and sign the package following [Signing Builds for Release](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/sign_builds).

When I attempted to sign the OTA package by running the following (quoted from [Signing Builds for Release](https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/sign_builds)):

```
make dist
sign_target_files_apks \
-o \    # explained in the next section
--default_key_mappings ~/.android-certs out/dist/*-target_files-*.zip \
signed-target_files.zip
```

`sign_target_files_apks` throws an error:

```
build_super_image.py - WARNING : Skip building super image because the following images are missing from target files:
/tmp/targetfiles-1KVO0M/IMAGES/vendor.img
```

And shows a trace at the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/__main__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/internal/stdlib/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/sign_target_files_apks.py", line 1420, in <module>
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/sign_target_files_apks.py", line 1413, in main
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/add_img_to_target_files.py", line 1039, in main
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/add_img_to_target_files.py", line 985, in AddImagesToTargetFiles
  File "/home/dean/proj/aosp12/out/soong/host/linux-x86/bin/sign_target_files_apks/add_img_to_target_files.py", line 606, in CheckAbOtaImages
AssertionError: Failed to find vendor.img
```

Some testing I've done revealed that the error occurs only after vendor binaries are added to the build, as instructed in [Google's documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download/downloading#obtaining-proprietary-binaries). Executing `sign_target_files_apks` without adding vendor binaries finishes successfully. I attempted to reproduce the error on AOSP 13 with a different target device and achieved the same results: `sign_target_files_apks` error occurs only after vendor binaries are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

There's a patch by PixelExperience, intended for AOSP 10, but applicable to AOSP 12.
The patch can be found on [Github](https://github.com/PixelExperience/build/commit/8d0487a778a78a37866aa71d4305ebbc97ae8861) and also on their [Gerrit](https://gerrit.pixelexperience.org/c/build/+/6473).

To elaborate further:

The patch modifies `sign_target_files_apks.py` located under `build/make/tools/releasetools` or `build/tools/releasetools`. You can modify either file, they are linked and changes reflect.

In function `ProcessTargetFiles`: Replace line `if filename.startswith("IMAGES/"):` with line `if filename.startswith("IMAGES/") and not filename.endswith("vendor.img"):`

In function `main`: Replace line `new_args = ["--is_signing"]` with line `new_args = ["--is_signing", "--add_missing"]`

Make sure to rebuild AOSP with `make dist` before you attempt to run `sign_target_files_apks` because it's path resolves soong `out` folder.